# Count instances of event (by type) per combination of columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to count number of events (by type) by each user-date

```
UserName    Event             DateUTC
1           AppStart          2020-06-01
2           Loaded a Screen   2020-06-01
3           AppStart          2020-06-01
3           Loaded a Screen   2020-06-01
3           Loaded a Screen   2020-06-01
```

I've tried `df_screen.groupby(['UserName', 'DateUTC']).size()` by it will not differentiate between the type of events (AppStart and Loaded a Screen).

The expected output is:

```
UserName DateUTC       Event           Count
1        2020-06-01    AppStart        1
2        2020-06-01    Loaded a Screen 1
3        2020-06-01    AppStart        1
3        2020-06-01    Loaded a Screen 2
```

Comment: `df_screen.groupby(['UserName', 'DateUTC', 'Event']).size()`?

Comment: Wow. Had not realized it'd be this simple. Thank you